# Showing 2 points are antipodal

Tags: calculus, geometry, proof-writing

There's 2 points $P, Q$ which are antipodal to each other (on the same line through the origin). Show that P and Q, on a unit sphere S are antipodal if and only if the tangent planes to S at P and Q are parallel to each other.

I don't have a clear solution to this question which is why I am asking. First, to start off, the unit sphere is $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Using this, we can determine the tangent plane of a random point P or Q. I noticed that the if the tangent planes at point P and Q are parallel, then the normal vectors are the same. How shall I continue the proof from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, we have points $P (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $Q (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ on unit sphere. Normal vectors to the tangent planes at $P$ are $Q$ are then simply $ \hat n_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $ \hat n_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$.

If $P$ and $Q$ are antipodal, midpoint of segment $PQ$ will be the origin, which leads to,

$\frac{x_0 + x_1}{2} = \frac{y_0 + y_1}{2} = \frac{z_0 + z_1}{2} = 0 $
$\implies (x_0, y_0, z_0) = - (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ or $\hat n_0 = - \hat n_1$.

So for $P$ and $Q$ to be antipodes, we must have tangent planes at $P$ and $Q$ parallel to each other.